# How to hash based on host + path in Varnish?

Tags: varnish

I want to use the [hash director](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vmod_directors.generated.html#obj-hash) in Varnish to redirect all requests for a same URL *without query parameters* to the same server:

For example,

```
http://example.com/foo/bar?a=1
http://example.com/foo/bar?a=2&b=3
```

Should hash to the same server. I want to hash on **host** and **path** only.

Here is my configuration:

```
sub vcl_init {
    new workers = directors.hash();

    workers.add_backend(worker_1, 1);
    workers.add_backend(worker_2, 1);
    workers.add_backend(worker_3, 1);
}
```

I understand I need to set the hash function here:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = workers.backend(...);
}
```

**What should I put in there to hash on host + path, without query string?**

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like the default VCL-provided `req` object provides a way to get the request *path*, without query parameters, just the full URL.  Thus using some VMODs might help.

You might try using the [`QueryString`](https://github.com/Dridi/libvmod-querystring) VMOD, *e.g.* (from their docs):

```
import querystring;

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.method == "GET" || req.method == "HEAD") {
        hash_data(querystring.remove(req.url));
    }
    else {
        hash_data(req.url);
    }
    hash_data(req.http.host);
    return (lookup);
}
```

And another nice VMOD, [`VSLP`](https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmod/vslp-stateless-persistence-consistent-hashing-director-vmod) might also be of interest, given the increased control it provides over backend selection.

Using Varnish 4.1, you might be able to use:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host) {
        set req.backend_hint = workers.backend(req.http.host + regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", ""));
    }
    else {
        set req.backend_hint = workers.backend(server.ip + regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", ""));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm afraid the QueryString vmod doesn't support Varnish 4 at the moment. Also, I would be grateful if you could provide a turnkey configuration to match my requirements, i.e. what to put in `req.backend_hint`!

Comment: @Benjamin: I'll certainly try.  Just to make sure: what's the exact Varnish version you're running?

Comment: At the moment I'm running 4.1!

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer, I'll need to test your suggestions before accepting it, in the meantime, enjoy the bounty!

Comment: For posterity: the correct syntax is `set req.backend_hint = workers.backend(req.http.host + regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", ""));`. Note the `+` instead of the `,` and `\?` instead of `?`. @Castaglia, maybe you want to update your answer? BTW, it works perfectly like that, thanks again!